# CSS Hover only works on bottom half of button

Tags: html, css

I have a few CSS-styled buttons on the navigation on my HTML web-page that has a glass effect to it.  However, only the bottom-half (the half without the glass effect) actually appears as it is being hovered over. How can I fix this?

I've already tried tampering with multiple elements in both the CSS and HTML, yet nothing seems to fix it.

Here is my code:

```css
// For Main Navigation: 
#tray {
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
}

#tray li a {
  color: #404040;
}

#tray li#tray-active a {
  background-color: #DD1600;
  color: #FFF;
}

#tray li a:hover {
  background-color: #9F9F9F;
  color: #FFF;
}

//Glass Effect:
#tray-glass:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6px;
  left: 2px;
  width: calc(68% - 4px);
  height: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
  opacity: 0.15;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div id="tray-glass">
    <li id="tray-active"><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried it in jsFiddle but can't get it to work, can you ensure right styling is copied. Also, an ID can only be applied to an element, not multiple time. Try changing the IDs to classes if you intend on applying it to multiple classes.

Comment: First thing I can see is that you use the same `tray-glass` id attribute numerous times which is illegal, use class for multiple elements and use id for unique element.

Comment: Also your `#tray` rules in CSS don't match any `#tray` id in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem is due to the fact that your `:after` effect is positioned **on top** of your links. Because you have `position: absolute` and `top: 0` on the `:after`, it is in the same position as the `<a>` itself.

You can correct this in a number of ways:

- Setting a `z-index` on the `:after` which is lower than that of the `#tray-glass` element
- Not making the effect start at `top: 0`
- Not using `position: absolute`

To be able to have the background alongside functional links, I would recommend turning it into an entirely separate element (such as `#overlay`) rather than an `:after` pseudo-element, and making this new element a sibling of `#tray-glass`. From here, make sure to give the parent a `position: relative`.

```css
#tray {
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
}

#tray li a {
  color: #404040;
}

#tray li#tray-active a {
  background-color: #DD1600;
  color: #FFF;
}

#tray li a:hover {
  background-color: #9F9F9F;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0.6px;
  left: 2px;
  width: calc(68% - 4px);
  height: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
  opacity: 0.15;
  background: red /* Added for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<ul>
<div class="container">
  <div id="tray-glass">
    <li id="tray-active"><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="tray-glass">Name</span></a></li>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</ul>
```